# The target origin provided does not match the recipient window's origin

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, redirect

I am getting below error in console when I try to open a `Visualforce Page`.

> AuraAlohaFrameNavigator.js:5Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow':   The target origin provided ('https://ap2.lightning.force.com') does not match the recipient window's origin ('https://c.ap2.visual.force.com').

Below is my code on VF page

```
<apex:commandLink styleClass="responses{!item.Id}" action="{!redirectToResult} "target="_blank" rendered="{!resultCount != '0'}">
```

Works fine if I remove target="__blank". But page opens in same tab and in classic view. I want the same to open in new tab and in lightning similar to how it behaves in classic.

Comment: is lightning component nested inside vf page using linghtning out? Or visualforce is nested inside lightning using iframe/canvas app. the code snippet you provide is VF code. What is on lightning side?

Comment: It's an existing vf page only. I want to make it lightning compatible. There is no lightning component.

Comment: May be you can check user context and update your accordingly. please refer https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2016/02/lightning-components-visualforce-lightning.html

Comment: I have done that. I checked the theme. If in SF Classic I use the existing one. If in lightning I am using sforce.one method for navigation. But sforce.one navigation opens the page in same tab. I want the the page to be opened in new tab same like sf classic.

Comment: I just encountered a very similar error message with an `apex:actionFunction` in a Visualforce page. I my case the problem stemmed from the developer console appending `?core.apexpages.request.devconsole=1` on the pages query string. Removing that changed the page structure an allowed it to work.